# Show non printable characters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping

Is it possible to visualize non-printable characters in a python string with its hex values?

e.g. If I have a string with a newline inside I would like to replace it with `\x0a`.

I know there is `repr()` which will give me ...`\n`, but I'm looking for the hex version.

Comment: The built-in codec `string_escape` (`s.encode('string_escape')`) almost does what you want, giving you hex for everything but `\t`, `\r` and `\n`, but unfortunately, as far as I know, there's nothing built-in that doesn't treat those three special…

Comment: Hmm ... does not work for me. "LookupError: unknown encoding: string_escape" I get.

Comment: Sorry, `string_escape` only exists in 2.x; you want `unicode_escape` in 3.x. But in addition to using `\t`, `\r`, `\n`, that will _also_ escape all characters `> \u00ff` (or maybe `> \u007f`? I forget…), which means it's even less likely you'll be happy with it out of the box… (The reason I put this as a comment rather than an answer is that I didn't expect you to be happy with the built-in codecs, given that your main point is that you want `\x0a` in place of `\n`.)

Comment: As a side note, since you're in 3.x, and using `str` rather than `bytes` strings: What do you want to do for non-printable non-ASCII characters? Replace them with Unicode escapes (e.g., `\u1234`), or something different?

Comment: No I'm dealing with bytes which I show as a string of one byte chars + the non printable chars which will show up as hex.

Comment: Are you _sure_ these are `bytes` objects (as in `b'abc\ndef'`) and not `str` objects (as in `'abc\ndef'`)? Because if it's the latter, you don't have a string of one byte chars, you have a string of Unicode chars, each taking anywhere from 1-6 or more bytes (depending on 3.0-3.2 vs. 3.3, how your Python was built, and which characters they are, but usually you don't care).

Comment: Well it depends on which point in the process you look at. If they are coming from the UI they are surely str objects. But in models and database are bytes.

Comment: I suppose that depends on what database API you're using, but anything that follows the standard DB-API (like sqlite3) returns `str` for `CHAR` columns, and `bytes` only for `BINARY` columns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to make the translation manually; go through the string with a regular expression for example, and replace each occurrence with the hex equivalent.

```
import re

replchars = re.compile(r'[\n\r]')
def replchars_to_hex(match):
    return r'\x{0:02x}'.format(ord(match.group()))

replchars.sub(replchars_to_hex, inputtext)
```

The above example only matches newlines and carriage returns, but you can expand what characters are matched, including using `\x` escape codes and ranges.

```
>>> inputtext = 'Some example containing a newline.\nRight there.\n'
>>> replchars.sub(replchars_to_hex, inputtext)
'Some example containing a newline.\\x0aRight there.\\x0a'
>>> print(replchars.sub(replchars_to_hex, inputtext))
Some example containing a newline.\x0aRight there.\x0a
```

Comment: This version is 4 times faster than iterating through the string as suggested in the other answers using a comprehension expression. To fully replace unprintable, use the following re: `re.compile('([^' + re.escape(string.printable) + '])')`, or some other char set (depending on what you want for newlines, etc.)

Comment: Use `re.compile(r'[\x00-\x1f]')` to match only control characters.

Answer (score 20):

I don't know of any built-in method, but it's fairly easy to do using a comprehension:

```
import string
printable = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation + ' '
def hex_escape(s):
    return ''.join(c if c in printable else r'\x{0:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in s)
```

Comment: This works for ASCII strings, but in 3.x, you can't count on a string being ASCII. And it's not quite as trivial to handle Unicode (although not _that_ hard).

Comment: For example: `hex_escape('a•')` will return `'abc\\x2022'`, which is not correct (it will turn into `'a 22'` when you unescape it).

Comment: why not just use string.printable ?

Comment: @GreenAsJade `string.printable` includes newline.

Comment: Doh ! :)   I wasn't interested in newline when I came searching for an answer to my own question, so I missed that ... makes sense now.

Answer (score 19):

I'm kind of late to the party, but if you need it for simple debugging, I found that this works:

```
string = "\n\t\nHELLO\n\t\n\a\17"

procd = [c for c in string]
        
print(procd)

# Prints ['\n,', '\t,', '\n,', 'H,', 'E,', 'L,', 'L,', 'O,', '\n,', '\t,', '\n,', '\x07,', '\x0f,']
```

---

While just `list` is simpler, a comprehension makes it easier to add in filtering/mapping if necessary.

Comment: `procd = list(string)` would be more concise than a trivial list comprehension.

Comment: For control code characters (not printable) its nice to be able to *see* them - `chr(ord(c) + 9216)` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Pictures

Answer (score 3):

Modifying ecatmur's solution to handle non-printable non-ASCII characters makes it less trivial and more obnoxious:

```
def escape(c):
    if c.printable():
        return c
    c = ord(c)
    if c <= 0xff:
        return r'\x{0:02x}'.format(c)
    elif c <= '\uffff':
        return r'\u{0:04x}'.format(c)
    else:
        return r'\U{0:08x}'.format(c)

def hex_escape(s):
    return ''.join(escape(c) for c in s)
```

Of course if `str.isprintable` isn't exactly the definition you want, you can write a different function. (Note that it's a very different set from what's in `string.printable`—besides handling non-ASCII printable and non-printable characters, it also considers `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\x0b`, and `\x0c` as non-printable.

You can make this more compact; this is explicit just to show all the steps involved in handling Unicode strings. For example:

```
def escape(c):
    if c.printable():
        return c
    elif c <= '\xff':
        return r'\x{0:02x}'.format(ord(c))
    else:
        return c.encode('unicode_escape').decode('ascii')
```

Really, no matter what you do, you're going to have to handle `\r`, `\n`, and `\t` explicitly, because all of the built-in and stdlib functions I know of will escape them via those special sequences instead of their hex versions.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar once by deriving a `str` subclass with a custom `__repr__()` method which did what I wanted. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but may give you some ideas.

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

# special string subclass to override the default
# representation method. main purpose is to
# prefer using double quotes and avoid hex
# representation on chars with an ord > 128
class MsgStr(str):
    def __repr__(self):
        # use double quotes unless there are more of them within the string than
        # single quotes
        if self.count("'") >= self.count('"'):
            quotechar = '"'
        else:
            quotechar = "'"

        rep = [quotechar]
        for ch in self:
            # control char?
            if ord(ch) < ord(' '):
                # remove the single quotes around the escaped representation
                rep += repr(str(ch)).strip("'")
            # embedded quote matching quotechar being used?
            elif ch == quotechar:
                rep += "\\"
                rep += ch
            # else just use others as they are
            else:
                rep += ch
        rep += quotechar

        return "".join(rep)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s1 = '\tWürttemberg'
    s2 = MsgStr(s1)
    print "str    s1:", s1
    print "MsgStr s2:", s2
    print "--only the next two should differ--"
    print "repr(s1):", repr(s1), "# uses built-in string 'repr'"
    print "repr(s2):", repr(s2), "# uses custom MsgStr 'repr'"
    print "str(s1):", str(s1)
    print "str(s2):", str(s2)
    print "repr(str(s1)):", repr(str(s1))
    print "repr(str(s2)):", repr(str(s2))
    print "MsgStr(repr(MsgStr('\tWürttemberg'))):", MsgStr(repr(MsgStr('\tWürttemberg')))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to print non-printable characters in the sense of them executing as commands within the string even if not visible (transparent) in the string, and their presence can be observed by measuring the length of the string using `len` as well as by simply putting the mouse cursor at the start of the string and seeing/counting how many times you have to tap the arrow key to get from start to finish, as oddly some single characters can have a length of 3 for example, which seems perplexing. (Not sure if this was already demonstrated in prior answers)

In this example screenshot below, I pasted a 135-bit string that has a certain structure and format (which I had to manually create beforehand for certain bit positions and its overall length) so that it is interpreted as ascii by the particular program I'm running, and within the resulting printed string are non-printable characters such as the <strike>'line break` which literally causes a line break</strike> (correction: form feed, new page I meant, not line break) in the printed output there is an extra entire blank line in between the printed result (see below):

[Example of printing non-printable characters that appear in printed string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Yxl.png)

```
Input a string:100100001010000000111000101000101000111011001110001000100001100010111010010101101011100001011000111011001000101001000010011101001000000
HPQGg]+\,vE!:@
>>> len('HPQGg]+\,vE!:@')
17
>>>
```

In the above code excerpt, try to copy-paste the string `HPQGg]+\,vE!:@` straight from this site and see what happens when you paste it into the Python IDLE.

**Hint:** You have to tap the arrow/cursor three times to get across the two letters from `P` to `Q` even though they appear next to each other, as there is actually a `File Separator` ascii command in between them.

However, even though we get the same starting value when decoding it as a byte array to hex, if we convert that hex back to bytes they look different (perhaps lack of encoding, not sure), but either way the above output of the program prints non-printable characters (I came across this by chance while trying to develop a compression method/experiment).

```
>>> bytes(b'HPQGg]+\,vE!:@').hex()
'48501c514767110c5d2b5c2c7645213a40'
>>> bytes.fromhex('48501c514767110c5d2b5c2c7645213a40')
b'HP\x1cQGg\x11\x0c]+\\,vE!:@'

>>> (0x48501c514767110c5d2b5c2c7645213a40 == 0b100100001010000000111000101000101000111011001110001000100001100010111010010101101011100001011000111011001000101001000010011101001000000)
True
>>>
```

In the above 135 bit string, the first 16 groups of 8 bits from the big-endian side encode each character (including non-printable), whereas the last group of 7 bits results in the `@` symbol, as seen below:

[Technical breakdown of the format of the above 135-bit string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qikab.png)

And here as text is the breakdown of the 135-bit string:

```
10010000 = H (72)
10100000 = P (80)
00111000 = x1c (28 for File Separator) *
10100010 = Q (81)
10001110 = G(71)
11001110 = g (103)
00100010 = x11 (17 for Device Control 1) *
00011000 = x0c (12 for NP form feed, new page) *
10111010 = ] (93 for right bracket ‘]’
01010110 = + (43 for + sign)
10111000 = \ (92 for backslash)
01011000  = , (44 for comma, ‘,’)
11101100  = v (118)
10001010 = E (69)
01000010 = ! (33 for exclamation)
01110100 = : (58  for colon ‘:’)
1000000  =  @ (64 for ‘@’ sign)
```

So in closing, the answer to the sub-question about showing the non-printable as hex, in byte array further above appears the letters `x1c` which denote the file separator command which was also noted in the hint. The byte array could be considered a string if excluding the prefix `b` on the left side, and again this value shows in the print string albeit it is invisible (although its presence can be observed as demonstrated above with the hint and `len` command).